# HTML5 (Javascript included) Game, canvas setup error

Tags: javascript, html

I have set up a canvas in HTML5 exactly right (I think) I've got an error:

I've previously made a canvas game, and I have copied and pasted the code multiple times, It looks right to me, I've googled the HTML canvas
set up, I have got the same answer, please help!

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="jumpMan.js"></script>
    <canvas width="1000px" height="450px" id="canvas"></canvas>

</body>
</html>

//jumpMan.js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillRect(50,50,50,50);
```

My Error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null
>       at jumpMan.js:3 (anonymous) @ jumpMan.js:3

Comment: You can try to put script tag under canvas, because the canvas tag has not been rendered yet.

Comment: var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"), try replacing with a semicolon var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your content isn't rendered yet.

So you have to check if your content/document is rendered before accessing the DOM.

Try this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn, false) ;
function fn() { //get canvas access...}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've recently found out something else that also works:
If you move the  tags under the  tag, it will work.

```
<canvas width="1000px" height="450px" id="canvas" ></canvas>
<script src='jumpMan.js'></script>
```